# How to use variable value to access class member in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Not sure if this is possible:
i want to create a sub  with 2 inputs a

```
 Public sub testsub(byval x as string,byval y as string)
dim z as class specialdevicelcass
z.y = x
end sub
```

is this even posible, y variable will always be a member of the special device class

Comment: You don't need to pass "y" as an argument to testsub since you're not using it. If the "y" in z.y is a member of specialdeviceclass, then what you have written is the correct syntax for accessing it.

Comment: I actually need something like what i have posted as  what y is might change each time it is run.  eg. y ="ipaddress" one time then next time it might be y="serial" etc.)

Comment: y is a member of a class, it is **y** that denotes what to access, not y's contents. so `eg. y ="ipaddress" one time then next time it might be y="serial"` is not possible. You can create a function that returns the value of the property sent as an argument.

Comment: I am going to to use a select case i up voted your comment because it is the answer but it will not let me select it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection for this:

```
Public Sub testsub(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String)
    Dim z As New specialdevicelcass
    Dim prop = z.GetType.GetProperty(y)
    prop.SetValue(z, x)
End Sub
```

Comment: i had to use prop.setvalue(z,x) in order to set the value